# Need Connector for Motor - I don't want to buy 50

Tags: electric-bike

I have no idea what I've gotten myself into, but I've bought electric bicycle motors and they didn't come with the connectors. Apparently the below link is the type of connectors I need. Is there an alternative distributor of these that I can buy just a couple from? Can I make them my self or cut them off and use a different connector?

Also is this type of connector standard? Is there a datasheet for these pin-outs somewhere?

[I would like to get 2 of these, not 50](http://www.batterybikekit.com/en/waterproof-plugin-for-bf-ebike-motor/127-9-core-waterproof-plug-in-connector-for-bf-ebike-motor.html)

Comment: I would suggest a good picture of the inside of the connector posted at [Electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) would get you some good pointers on where to find a replacement.

Comment: I suggest emailing that wholesaler and asking whether there's a retailer near you, or whether they have a list of online retailers you could buy from.

Comment: Could you change both sides of the connector rather than looking for something to match what you have?  Or try looking for a reseller, the link you've found is a wholesaler who wants to deal in bulk rather than retail shoppers like yourself.

Comment: As @criggie says. The connectors are probably used in other applications as well and someone will sell in smaller volumes. Even try eBay. Plenty of shops there but specialist parts in large packs, split, apply a decent markup and sell.

Comment: So this question is 10 months old.  What did you do, how did it work for you?  Feel free to post an answer to your own question and accept it (that's totally permitted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First 9-Core Waterproof Plug in connector at Green Bike Kit

http://www.greenbikekit.com/9pin-waterproof-connector-cable.html

This was the 3rd result when I googled "9-Core Waterproof Plug in connector"